# ¿Como super poner div con css?

Tags: css

Tengo un div que es una especie de contenedor (que tambien tiene estilo) y quiero poner otros dos div, uno a la izquierda con una imagen y otro a la derecha con opciones. Estoy tratando de hacerlo pero honestamente no se porque no sale el segundo div.

Lo que estoy tratando de lograr es esto (perdon por la resolucion):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```css
.sub-menu1-container {
 margin: 0 5%;
 background: white;
 height: 337px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px grey;
 position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

.sub-menu1-img {
 padding: 1% 10%;
 position: absolute;
}

.sub-menu1-options {
 background: grey;
 position: absolute; 
 right: 10%;
 height: 337px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sub-menu1-container">
  <div class="sub-menu1-img">
    <img src="http://www.ikea.com/PIAimages/0324126_PE517034_S5.JPG" style="width: 300px; height: 320px;">
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu1-options">
    
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Pero por alguna razon no sale el div que deberia tener fondo gris. Pueden ayudarme?

Comment: intentastes agregarle texto a los div para ver como se comportan?

Comment: No @JackNavaRow no lo he hecho, pero no deberia ser necesario o si?

Comment: Acabo de agregarle width al div y aparecio sin texto. Hare un par de pruebas mas y si todo esta bien publicare una autorespuesta.

Comment: te iba a escrtibir esa opcion o agregar width o escrbir el texto en el div, el div lo necesita para dimensionarse

Comment: Si @JackNavaRow gracias! Pues, creo que, si quisieras publicar una respuesta indicando que se puede agregar texto o width para visualizarlo seria un buen aporte. Tambien Depiro ha hecho una buena contribucion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código es correcto pero el div .sub-menu1-options no tiene contenido por eso no aparece.

```css
.sub-menu1-container {
 margin: 0 5%;
 background: white;
 height: 337px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px grey;
 position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

.sub-menu1-img {
 padding: 1% 10%;
 position: absolute;
}

.sub-menu1-options {
 background: grey;
 position: absolute; 
  right: 10%;
 height: 337px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sub-menu1-container">
  <div class="sub-menu1-img">
    <img src="http://www.ikea.com/PIAimages/0324126_PE517034_S5.JPG" style="width: 300px; height: 320px;">
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu1-options">

    <ul>
      <li>item menu</li>
      <li>item menu</li>
      <li>item menu</li>
      <li>item menu</li>
      <li>item menu</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: puedes agregar el ejemplo en el sitio para que lo pueda visualizar

Comment: Si creo que seria bueno. Ademas, ya me di cuenta que cuando le agrego un valor a width si aparece mi div, creo que ese era el principal problema.

Answer (score 1):

No se muestra el `div` de la derecha ya que no le has asignado una anchura (o le has asignado algún tipo de contenido).

Te propongo ponerle una anchura a ambos `div` (en este caso les he asignado la mitad del espacio del contenedor a cada uno).

Por otro lado, al ser dos `div` posicionados como `absolute`, tu tienes la propiedad `right: 10%` en el `div` que se encuentra en la parte derecha, lo que superpondrá el `div` que se encuentra en la parte derecha sobre el que está a la izquierda. Yo te recomiendo que pongas `right: 0`, y, en caso de que quisieras que hubiera uno más grande y otro más pequeño, ir jugando con las anchuras de ambos `div` hasta completar la totalidad del `div` contenedor. Por ejemplo: 60% y 40%, 70% y 30%, etc...

Si quitaras la propiedad `right: 0` del `div` de la derecha, este se pondría encima del `div` de la izquierda ya que, al estar posicionado de manera absoluta, no toma en cuenta el resto de elementos y toma como referencia su contenedor padre que esté posicionado, por lo que ambos `div` se posicionarían tomando como referencia la esquina superior izquierda del contenedor.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
.sub-menu1-container {
  margin: 0 5%;
  background: white;
  height: 337px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px grey;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.sub-menu1-img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1% 10%;
  position: absolute;
}

.sub-menu1-options {
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0%;
  height: 337px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sub-menu1-container">
  <div class="sub-menu1-img">
    <img src="http://www.ikea.com/PIAimages/0324126_PE517034_S5.JPG" style="width: 300px; height: 320px;">
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu1-options">
    
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> utiliza el **z-index: 1000;** como superior y los inferiores les asignas menos de mil; usa para hacer el div visible **border-style: solid;** haci si no te sale ya estas mas seguro de que estan en capas inferiores.